# Unauthenticated response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

- Passport Version: used in joselfonseca/laravel-api
- Laravel Version: 8
- PHP Version: 7
- Database Driver & Version: Mysqli

#### Description:

Included bearer token but receiving response as unauthenticated,
Response,
{
"message": "Unauthenticated.",
"status_code": 401
}

#### Steps To Reproduce:

Tried this link to get list of users - http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users
And I have included authorization header with bearer token in post man. but I can't get the result.
Pls help me to solve this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Passport invalid\_grant for password grant\_type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60123601/laravel-passport-invalid-grant-for-password-grant-type)

Answer (score 0):

Try to revoke all of your tokens with the following code and then login again and pass that newly generated token with your request. Hope this will resolve your issue.

```
$tokens = auth()->user()-tokens;
foreach($tokens as $token) {
    $token->revoke();   
}
```